# why ChildNodes returns XmlNodeList with blank values

Tags: uwp, xmldocument

```
XmlNodeList NodeList = Node.ChildNodes;
```

here Node is an object of IXmlNode. ChildNodes()  retuns NodeList  with alternate blank values and orginal values.

Xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Service>
<Name Value="122" ValueType="string"/>
<Number Value="1222" ValueType="long"/>
<ApplicationName Value="Service" ValueType="string"/>
<Count Value="10" ValueType="long"/>
</Service>
```

Actually 4 child nodes are here, but nodelist contains 9 child node (blank and orginal values )

Comment: Are the extras for the whitespace between the nodes?

Comment: i recommand to use Xdocument, this is more clean and much easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

@Peter Torr - MSFT's guess was right. @Roshmi Benny I used your XML content to create a xml file in my UWP project and use [Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.xml.dom.xmldocument) relevant APIs to load this xml file, then I also got 9 child nodes in my code. But there're five whitespace node (`\n`) in it. You could set `XmlLoadSettings.ElementContentWhiteSpace=false` to disable it.

See the following code sample:

```cs
StorageFile file = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("XMLFile1.xml");
XmlLoadSettings settings = new XmlLoadSettings();
settings.ElementContentWhiteSpace = false;
Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument xmlDocument = await Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(file,settings);
XmlNodeList xmlNodes = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Service");
foreach (var element in xmlNodes)
{
    XmlNodeList nodes = element.ChildNodes;
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        //TODO:......
    }
}
```

[image]